# Difference between verb-subject and subject-verb

Tags: meaning, verbs, difference, word-order

I have read the following sentence:

> Perché è dovuto succedere questo?

Would "Perché questo è dovuto succedere?" be also correct? What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences? Emotional involvement?

Comment: Consider also “Perché è dovuto succedere?”, I'd say the most natural phrasing.

Comment: It's a question of emphasis. The verb is intransitive and the subject is frequently postponed.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker, I feel that in the first version:

> Perché è dovuto succedere questo?

The stress is on asking why that happened in the first place. The thing was not meant to happened at all.

While in:

> Perché questo è dovuto succedere?

Is more on what happened. Maybe something different could have happened instead bringing less pain.

That said, I feel is a very slight nuance.